# Drupal 7.5 Is there a record of what user delete file?

Tags: drupal-7

Is there a way to detect which user deletes a file in Drupal 7.5? The `file_managed` table appears to just remove the entry. Marking it deleted and adding the user_id would be ideal for accountability. I'm trying to solve an issue a client is having with disappearing files. The files have already been deleted. I'm not seeing any relevant `file_*` tables to join. File system just shows file are gone.

Follow up: if not, is there a way to detect what users deleted a file in Drupal 8.x? This could be a motivating factor to consider upgrading.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this module would work for you:

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_delete_log